# Ajax random changes URL query parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I am using AJAX only to prevent redirect to a shopping cart.

As the result I have an item with **random** quantity in the cart.

Link itself pasted to an address bar works perfect, and gives specified quantity.
But when I do it with AJAX it gives **wrong quantity**.

**What is wrong in this code, or how could I specify quantity in other way?**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '#url_cart', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault(); //prevent redirect
          $.ajax($(this).attr('href')).done(function(response) { 
               });
         });
        </script>
        <!-- link for the item -->
<a 
    id="url_cart" 
    href="http://localhost:4000/cart.php?action=add&product_id={{id}}&variation_id=currency_id=&qty[]=1">
    {{lang 'products.add_to_cart'}}
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging `$(this).attr('href')` to see what it is and if it has the correct qty?

Comment: @Taplar Just tried! Interesting, I get always 12 console logs! Quantity in the Cart still different, like 3, 5 etc. Important, I have 12 links on my page with the same id. So looks like AJAX perform itself for each link?! Qty in the link is always correct.

Comment: Sounds like you are binding multiple times on an element

Comment: @Taplar how can I try to prevent it?

Comment: I mean, you shouldn't have that.  You really shouldn't even have 12 elements that match that event cause you are doing a delegate binding and your child selector is an id, and you can't repeat ids.

Comment: @Taplar This is Bigcommerce Stencil. Main page render 1 card.html for each item. So 12 times repeating. My AJAX is in this card.html. That is why I have the same ID.

Comment: Then that's invalid markup.  But even then, that shouldn't cause clicking one to trigger 12 clicks, unless you are performing your binding 12 times.  You should only be performing this binding once.  If you are including it on an html that is being done 12 times, then this should not be done in that page, but on a more global include that is only done once.

Answer (score 0):

This is Bigcommerce Stencil. In my case main page render 1 card.html for each item. So 12 times repeating. My AJAX is in this card.html.
@Taplar said right, I am

> binding multiple times on an element

So I gave unique ID for each link (in this case {{id}} == item ID):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#{{id}}', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax($(this).attr('href')).done(function(response) { 
           });
     });
    </script>

     <a id="{{id}}" 
href="http://localhost:4000/cart.php?action=add&product_id={{id}}&variation_id=currency_id=&qty[]=1">
   {{lang 'products.add_to_cart'}}
      </a>
```

Now it works perfect! 
Thanks Taplar!